# Software does not give me the option of where to save the software during install

Tags: installation

I need to download software for my daughter's toy. It's called Learning Lodge Navigator for the MobiGo2, and it can be found here: http://www.vtechkids.com/download/. I only want Windows 7 operating system files and updates on my C: drive. Everything else, I have on my D: drive. The problem is that this software does not allow me to choose where I would like to install it; it just begins to install on the C: drive.

What can I do to resolve this? If I download to C: drive and just copy files to D: drive, that may cause a problem, right?

Comment: Have you tried VTech support or KB?  This may not be doable and as ypou suspecvt, mving after install will most likely fail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [ntfs soft links (aka junctions)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365006%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to fool that software installer. Let's say it wants to install itself into `C:\MOBIGO2` and you want it in `D:\Programs\MobiGo2`. You just create the latter and link it to the former. This way the installer would think it is copying the files on to drive `C:` when in fact the files would be stored on the drive `D:`

Run the following commands as administrator:

```
mkdir D:\Programs\MobiGo2
mklink /j C:\MobiGo2 D:\Programs\MobiGo2
```

After this all files copied to C:\MobiGo2 will be stored in D:\Programs\MobiGo2

Comment: I've never heard of this before. So, how do I go about linking? Do I need to use the command line?

Comment: Will give it a go. Also, I had to install Adobe Flash Player to install these programs for my daughter's toy, and encountered the same issue. I'm going to try this on both right now, and see if it works (obviously, I will uninstall and reinstall the AFP.)

Comment: Well, I'm trying this with Adobe Flash Player. I created a directory called D:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Flash Player since the Adobe Flash Player originally installed in the same directory on the C: drive. I then went to Command Line and entered this command: mklink /j C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Flash Player D:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Flash Player. It said, "The syntax of the command is incorrect." Any ideas?

Comment: mklink /j "C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Flash Player" "D:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Flash Player"

Comment: also you can install the software first. then move the files to the desired location and only then make a link to the original location

Comment: I successfully created the junction point, then installed Adobe Flash Player (x86). A question though: I can't see the software in the D:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Flash Player folder. Why is that? (I was attempting to make a junction point for Adobe Flash Player because it did not give me the option of which drive to install on.)

Comment: please try the other way I suggested. uninstall the software. remove the "C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Flash Player" if still there. installl the software. Move the "C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Flash Player" folder to D: drive. make the link.

Comment: Moving a program from one drive to another is something I wanted to avoid in the first place. =)

Comment: No. you wanted to have your software files to be stored on the drive D. that's where they will be after you move them. What you wanted to avoid was the software no longer working after you move it. That's what the link I suggested you create would take care of. With the link the files are still going to be available at the C drive location while stored on the D drive.

Comment: Ah, got it. I will try this again then. Do you think I need to get rid of the junction link I already made? I mean, it will be the same name...